# Verb + Object Pronoun + Object or Verb + Object + Object Pronoun

Tags: pronouns, subject-vs-object-pronouns

Most of time I am confused when making the sentences, like so:

- Verb + Object Pronoun + Object
- Verb + Object + Object Pronoun

Here's some examples:

- Send me e-mail.
- Post me them.
- Post me the socks.
- Send e-mail me *OR* Send e-mail to me.

Which one is the correct answer? Please, give me some examples *OR* give some examples me *(?)*

Comment: We can say "Post me the socks" or "Post the socks to me", but "Post me them" sounds odd; it would normally be "Post them to me".

Comment: As far as I understand If there are two objects, we should say that `"Send + Object + to Object Pronoun"` or `"Send + Object + noun"`, like so: `"Send it to me"` or `"Send me the e-mail"`.